# Split large csv files in perl

Tags: perl, split

I am trying to split the CSV file which has 1.5 million rows

Example:

```
test;abc;kk
test1;abc1;kk1
```

The above complete data exists under the first column of CSV

I am trying to map these fields to json object by trying to read the csv line by line but not getting desired output. I am not suppose use text::csv due to some official issues

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n";

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) {
     chomp $line;
     my @fields = split ";" , $line;
     for (my $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
       print "$fields[$i] ";
     }
}

My output now shows 
        t e s t ; a b c ; k k ; t e s t 1 ; a b c 1 ; k k 1.
```

I am not getting preferred output. I might have done some mistake
Once I run the code I get

Expected output should be for first iteration.... then next line for second iteration

```
  fields[0] = test
  fields[1] = abc
  fields[2] = kk
```

Comment: Are you also not using the `JSON` module due to those same official issues? It is not obvious what is wrong with your code or your output. You should show expected output, and actual output. You are splitting on semi-colon and space, this is not what your csv data is using, so it will not work.

Comment: Also, no, your output should never contain `fields[0]` because that is not in your code. It should be `test abc kk`

Comment: My output now shows t e s t ; a b c ; k k ; t e s t 1 ; a b c 1 ; k k 1.

Comment: I will never use fields[0].... I just gave an example. Since I need read large rows all will be running inside loop. I want to know what is the mistake

Comment: You should only show expected output *exactly* the way it should appear. The output does not show that with the code in the question. It would say that if you split on the empty string, but you don't do that. Only show the exact code you use, the output you expected to get, and the exact output you get, and nothing else.

Comment: People outside India aren't going to understand what are "lakh rows". Please don't use Indian words like "lakh" or "lac" here.

Comment: `lakh` means millions does it? Then you REALLY should use `Text::CSV` with its XS parts, as it is a lot more efficient.

Comment: Yes correct. It is millions

Comment: I would like to know what is the issue in that piece of code.

Comment: @RamPr Your code and output do not match. Either you are not telling the truth, or you are not executing the code you think you are. We can do nothing further to help you until you correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next code, be sure that on split command you have used the proper separator:

```
split ";" , $line;
```

Here is the perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n";

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

my $line_no = 0;
while (my $line = <$data>) {
     chomp $line;
     $line_no++;
     print "Line $line_no:\n";
     my @fields = split ";" , $line;
     for (my $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
       print "fields[$i] = $fields[$i]\n";
     }
}
```

Here is the content of input file

```
test;abc;kk
test1;abc1;kk1
```

and here is the output

```
Line 1:
fields[0] = test
fields[1] = abc
fields[2] = kk
Line 2:
fields[0] = test1
fields[1] = abc1
fields[2] = kk1
```